# c - in a series of input using scanf, last value is not being printed ( using printf )

Tags: c

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    float k, l;
    char a, b;
    scanf("%d%d%f%f%c%c", &i, &j, &k, &l, &a, &b);
    printf("%d %d %f %f %c %c", i, j, k, l, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The program takes in all the six inputs but prints **only** first 5 variables.

Can anyone please point out the problem in my concept/program ?

Comment: Not checking the return value from scanf is a sure recipe for surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted, the problem is with `%c`

> scanf("%d%d%f%f%c%c", &i, &j, &k, &l, &a, &b);

As it stands, given your input like below, then your last character `d` would not be read - instead a space right after `c` is interpreted as your character input:

```
1 2 3.0 4.0 c d
```

So your `scanf` should be changed to:

```
scanf("%d%d%f%f %c %c", &i, &j, &k, &l, &a, &b);  // <-- Notice there is a space before each %c to read over space characters
```

Note: C is indeed strange in this aspect, I guess everyone has to encounter this issue a few times before remembering this kind of weird issue - that you should always be careful with `%c` of `scanf`, and you need to add space before it to read character input properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would ask that if, while giving input, i press ENTER key after the fifth input and type the value, will i get the correct output?

Comment: Yeah, remember you still need a space before `%c` - it will skip all space characters (incl. Enter)

Answer (score 1):

To get a single character from the user in C, people use either `scanf()` with the format specifier `%c` or `getchar()`. Both functions read a character from the standard input stream (the difference between them is that `getchar()` reads just one character, whereas `scanf()` can read a variety of formats).

But both have the same pitfall: when the user enters a character and then afterwards presses the enter key. Thus there are actually two characters in the input stream: the character entered and the newline character.
If you don't remove the newline character from the input stream, it could interfere with input functions later in the program. It seems that the input is ignored.

Simple solution would be `scanf(" %c", &ch);`